# How to handle absent elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

For a medium sized app with a medium amount of javascript (in the way of jQuery), what's the best way to combine the javascript into a single file while also avoiding acting on absent elements?

For example, given the html:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Foobar</title></head>
  <body>
     <div id='foo'>Bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This will get bound
  $('#foo').click(function() { alert('foobar'); });

  // This will not get bound
  $('#bar').click(function() { alert('foobar'); });
});
```

Granted both of the above bindings are relatively innocuous, but for complex behaviors, will attempting to bind to absent elements cause a performance hit?  If so, how do you balance keeping your javascript in a single file (to decrease http requests) with maintainable, performant jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

The cost of not finding an element is basically the same of finding it.

So probably this won't cause a performance hit.

Comment: So unnecessarily searching for a lot of elements on the page when they aren't present on that page won't cause a performance hit?